# Constructing a tridiagonal matrix with some spectral information.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse-problems

I am going to construct a matrix of the following form
$$
T_n = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
b_1 & a_2 & b_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& b_2 & a_2 & b_3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b_{n-2} & a_{n-1} & b_{n-1} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & b_{n-1} & a_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

from the following eigen information:

- One eigenvalue of each of the leading principal's minors of $T_n$, named $\lambda^{(i)}$ for the $i$th leading principal minor
- One eigenpair of $T_n$, named eigenvector $X$ and eigenvalue $\lambda^{(n)}$

The solution to this problem is simple and is given in [this link](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/4/1/12). However, I have the restriction that I cannot use $T_nX = \lambda^{(n)}X$ for the first row.

### My Solution

The roots of $P_{n}(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_n-T_n)$ are the eigenvalues of $T_n$ and
\begin{equation}
P_{j}(\lambda) = (\lambda - a_j)P_{j-1}(\lambda) - b_{j-1}^2P_{j-2}(\lambda), j=3, 4, \cdots, n
\end{equation}

Therefore the solution is the following system of equations

\begin{align}
P_{j}(\lambda^{(j)}) &= 0 \\
T_nX &= \lambda^{(n)}X
\end{align}

where $P_j(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_j - T_j)$ and $T_j$ is the $j$th leading principal minor of $T_n$, i.e.

$$
T_j = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
b_1 & a_2 & b_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& b_2 & a_2 & b_3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b_{j-2} & a_{j-1} & b_{j-1} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & b_{j-1} & a_j
\end{bmatrix}
$$

From $P_{1}(\lambda^{(1)}) = 0$, it is easy to see $a_1 = \lambda^{(1)}$. For the second row:
\begin{align}
(\lambda^{(n)} - a_2)(\lambda^{(n)} - a_1) &= b_1^2\\
b_1x_1 + b_2x_3 &= (\lambda^{(n)} - a_2)x_2
\end{align}

and it gives

\begin{equation}
b_1^2\dfrac{x_2}{(\lambda^{(n)} - \lambda^{(1)})} - b_1x_1 - b_2x_3 = 0
\end{equation}

Unfortunately, I can't solve this because $b_2$ is also an unknown variable. If we continue this way, we will end up with

\begin{align}
(\lambda^{(n)} - a_n)P_{n-1}(\lambda^{(n)}) &= b_{n-1}^2P_{n-2}(\lambda^{(n)})\\
b_{n-1}x_{n-1} &= (\lambda^{(n)} - a_n)x_n
\end{align}

But I couldn't find a solution yet. I would like to know if it is possible to find a solution to this problem with the given data. Are the input enough to solve the problem? and if yes, what is the answer?

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Are there misprints in the last columns of $T_n$ and $T_j$ ? I guess the terms $b_{n-1}$ and $b_{j-1}$ are missing.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I rewrite the $T_n, T_j$ and added one more row. I guess it is OK now.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Is this your scholar? https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=6nHrWhsAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate

Comment: Is this problem determined? - I mean regarding number of equations.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi No it is not. it is just an example

Comment: Shouldn't be for the second row $(\lambda^{(2)} - a_2)(\lambda^{(2)} - a_1) = b_1^2$ instead of $\lambda^{(n)}?$